# Different theme for every activity

Tags: android, themes

I want every activity to have a different theme, for example:in the **MainActivity** I want the theme to be  `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` <-- I tried to add it under `android:name=".MainActivity"` but when I launch the app it crashes ( "unfortunately app has stopped." ).

Also if I try to change the `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"` into any other theme it tells me  "**You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.**"
What am i missing?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.alec_myd.www.alec" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/minion_hitman"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".second_activity"
                  android:label="@string/about">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".third_activity"
            android:label="@string/action_settings">

        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you have `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` set to your `SplashScreenActivity`. It extends `ActionBarActivity` which is a class of `appcompat` library. It requires a `Theme.Appcompat` theme to work properly. `Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen` is not a `Theme.Appcompat` theme.

I suggest you change the parent class for your `SplashScreenActivity` from `ActionBarActivity` to `Activity`, because you don't need an `ActionBar` in there:

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends Activity {
```

Now, you can set `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` for the `SplashScreenActivity`.

Comment: I checked the SpashScreenActivity.java and it looks just as you said: public class SplashScreenActivity extends Activity {        But the MainActivity.java looks like this: public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

Comment: Solved :D changed the class in the MainActivity.java to: public class MainActivity extends Activity {  <-- thanks a lot :D